Geometric intuition behind induced homology homomorphisms
This is certainly overkill...but at the moment, I'm trying to strengthen my geometric understanding towards homology groups. The current trouble I've been having is in understanding the geometric intuition behind why homotopic maps induce the same homomorphism on homology groups.
I understand the proofs (as well I understand the prism operator), but the additional intuition I'm looking for at the moment is with regards towards understanding what is actually happening. Like what examples are there that truly demonstrate why this fact is true? It seems so weird that an arbitrary condition such as $f_{\#}-g_{\#}$ mapping all cycles $\subset X$ to boundaries $\subset Y$ gives the result of two homology groups being isomorphic. How do I even begin to visualize this?
Thank you! (p.s., Notation here comes from Hatcher (pg. 111).)

" It seems so weird that an arbitrary condition [...]" There's an algebra side and a topology side to this proof of homotopy invariance, and this condition is quite firmly on the algebra side. You should attempt to understand the fact chain homotopic maps induce the same maps on homology away from any geometric input. Here's a start for the "arbitrary" condition you give: Homology is by def. "something modulo boundary", so an equation like $f_#(a) - g_#(a) = b$ holds on homology "up to boundary"; in particular, if $b$ is a boundary, then (again, up to boundary) $f_#(a) - g_#(a) = 0$.

...in other words, if $f_# - g_#$ lands in boundaries, then $f_* = g_*$ for the induced maps on homology. If you think a bit about this you'll hopefully come to agree that the condition is not arbitrary at all but quite natural :). For the geometric intuition, try think about a space you can visualize and understand well, e.g. $S^1$. Pick your favourite homotopic maps of the form, say, $S^1 \to S^1$, and see what you can figure out walking through the construction. Also, you might want to look at section 2.A for a different angle on this example.

Note that $f_#-g_#$ mapping all cycles to boundaries is not arbitrary but precisely (!!) the condition that you need for $f_\ast=g_\ast$ to hold!

But intuitively just view this as like, the higher dimensional analogue of the geometrically obvious fact that $H_1$ and $\pi_1$ should be homotopy invariant

@BenSteffan Makes sense. Appreciate your response (as always)! I'll give it some time after having read over 2.A -- as well consider your $S^1\to S^1$ map example -- and get back to you if confusion persists.

@FShrike yep, I realized only after posting this question that in fact the most intuitive expectation is for the mapping relationship w.r.t. boundaries and cycles to be precisely what we get. Looking at this from a non-algebraic lens, however, this continues to fail at making much intuitive sense to me. For instance, it is intuitively clear visually how homeomorphic maps would preserve topological invariants/properties.
